# Zeroing last 12 bits for mmap offset

Tags: c++, mmap

Why does zeroing the last 12bits of a mmap offset ensure it is a multiple of __SC_PAGE_SIZE?

For example:

```
offset = address & ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1);
```

Here PAGE_SIZE = 4096.

Comment: What if you think about it in decimal ?

Comment: Assuming all the information you give is correct, because `__SC_PAGE_SIZE` is a power of 2 that's less than or equal to the power of 2 (in the something times a power of 2) that you create by zeroing.

Answer (score 0):

```
4096dec = 00..001000000000000bin
```

If you're interested in zero'ing out all the bits preceding the 1, you do `PAGE_SIZE-1`:

```
00..000111111111111
```

The NOT operator ensures all the bits that aren't in these positions are considered:

```
~00..000111111111111 = 11..11000000000000
```

and you simply AND the address bits with the above to zero-out the zero portion above.

This is a commonly used bit-trick to get a value which is a multiple of a power-of-two number.

One thing you should notice: the code you posted might **decrease** the address value to get the offset as a power-of-two. I.e. if you enter 4500, you'll get the offset as 4096 (i.e. you dropped to the bottom-closest multiple of that power-of-two number.

The *address alignment* version is way more used:

```
aligned_address = (address + PAGE_SIZE -1) & ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1);
```

Comment: If I give 4500 as an address, then your code gives 8192.  I guess I need a lower address space? Like 2048?

Comment: Your code isn't the last one I posted but a "round to multiple of 2 number" by defect